# Spring application server to client data transmission via websocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, server, client

Question : Is it possible to send data from server to client in spring ,using websocket, without creating another client , in the java app that sustains the server ?

Almost every article on the internet about websocket in spring, shows how to define your methods in the controller for handling requests . All the magic seem to happen when they define a function with the 2 annotations @MessageMapping("/news") , @SendTo("/topic/news") . By having this method alone , as far as I know, you can only catch requests and  send them  further ( SendTo) . I want to know if it is possible to send data from server to client without having a client requesting something in the first place. And how that code would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use SimpMessagingTemplate .

i think you should have this class somewhere

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
 public class "yournameclass" extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
```

then this method inside

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry configuration) {
    configuration.enableSimpleBroker("/test");
    configuration.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/someprefix"); 
}
```

then you could call this from some method in your code

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


public void "mymethodsender" ()
{  this.template.convertAndSend("/test/somepathwhereyouregisteredyourclienttoreceivemessages", "messageobject");
}
```